# Script-file that builds web application

Tags: maven, web-applications, ant, build, packaging

I have created a `Java` web application using maven and I want to deploy it. Indeed my intention is to have it run in two different ways keeping the same code. To this effect I have created twice the class that initializes/starts the application: `MyApplication`. Each class of those should be used in each form of the application while the other should be ignored. I was informed that this is a matter of build and I should adjust the build to contain the appropriate classs for each form. That can be done probably with a `script-file` which defines and "excecutes" the build of the application. In other words it indicates, what files/classes must be contained in the deployed project and it builds them. I have not yet written such a `script-file` and I have no idea if it can be really done and how. Maybe in `ant`? Any idea?

Comment: You could implement a factory method, that returns the right instance of `MyApplication`, and set a system property, that determines which one to choose (eg. `-Dmy.application.mode=mode1`). You could also use Maven [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) to produce 2 different builds.

Comment: @SzymonBiliński: The MyApplication class has an init() method that starts the application. Where should the factory methory be placed? From the time the application has started, it is then late to call it. How could the property solve the problem since it can be set only to one value?

Comment: How is `MyApplication` instantiated (before `init()` is called)?

Comment: It is not (manually). It is a class that extends the standard class from framework, which starts the Application. One does not creates an Object of it.